# JavaFX stop KeyEvent after getting only one alpha numeric character

Tags: java, javafx, keyevent, onkeypress

I am new to Java and am having trouble on getting some code working. I have a GUI with the letters A-Z. After a button click, I want to ask for a Keyevent to do a couple of things:

1. Only allow you to select a letter. Upper or lower case. If not wait for a response that is correct.
2. Then check the alphabet list to see if it has been pressed before. If it has then ask for another letter
3. If a new character is entered then strike it out on the alphabet and run the method that follows
4. Disable any further keys being pressed.
   I have tried the following code:

   ```
   private static void spinGame(){

           switch (wheelResult)

           {
             case "1'
               ...

               break;
             case "2":
               ...

               break;

             default: 
               System.out.println("...");

               newPhrase.gameB();

               scene2.setOnKeyPressed((KeyEvent event) -> {
                   if (event.getText().isEmpty())
                       return;

                   char pressed = event.getText().toUpperCase().charAt(0);
                   userGuess=event.getText().charAt(0);

                   if ((pressed < 'A' || pressed > 'Z'))
                       return;


                       Text t = alphabet.get(pressed);
                    if (t.isStrikethrough())
                           return;

                       // mark the letter 'used'
                    else{t.setFill(Color.BLUE);
                       t.setStrikethrough(true);

                       System.out.println(userGuess);
                       }
                       int letterCount;
                       if ((userGuess == 'a') || (userGuess == 'e') || (userGuess == 'i') || (userGuess == 'o')    || (userGuess == 'u')){

                          playerScores[currentPlayer] -= 250;
                          System.out.println("£250 docked from score for vowel use");
                       }
   ```

It goes wrong from here. I dont want keys to be pressed again and I don't the following method should run:

```
                           letterCount = newPhrase.makeGuess(userGuess);

                            ...my method....;
                     })
```

I have no idea how to fix it. I tested and recorded the User guess is being selected but it does not proceed the method after and the key in input doesn't stop. I also feel that my coding for the alphanumeric stuff is wrong.

Comment: What you've provided looks fine, although there are a few small changes you can do to condense it. Unless the problem you are having isn't in the code you've provided? E.g initialising "alphabet", which I guessed when testing

Comment: The alphabet is set up. It cancels and works out fine. The issue is that i want to stop the key event until the method that calls it runs again.

Comment: Do you mean you want to stop checking letters after every letter in the alphabet has been guessed correctly?

Comment: How would i condense it?

Comment: userGuess and pressed hold the same value, you can condense it by only using one

Comment: I want to stop guessing the letters chosen before. So essentially it is a game like hangman. I press a button then I want the user to press one key (letter) not chosen before to see if it is in the phrase. My method after is not running :(

Comment: By checking if a guessed letter is strike-through you're already doing that. The code won't reach the scoring section if it is

Comment: The issue is if its not been strikedthrough. Then the method wont run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution already caters for your requirements as you check for a valid letter and whether or not it is strike-through in your alphabet. So until they provide an unused letter, nothing will happen aside from the conditions being checked each time

To stop the key input I'd recommend using a `ToggleButton` or something similar so the user has to indicate when they want to guess. This means you can use other text based controls with a decreased probability of striking off letters in your alphabet accidentally. When they guess an unused letter you can reset the button, otherwise keep checking their input for a valid letter

Your method relating to the scoring system is only called when a vowel has been entered by the user. You can separate the score and input logic by creating a method and only providing valid unused letters to it, handling the game's scoring/phrase lookup logic there:

```
private void checkPhrase(char chosenLetter){
    //Handle the Hangman-like logic here
    boolean isVowel = vowels.indexOf(chosenLetter) >= 0;
    if (isVowel) {
        System.out.println("User provided a vowel");
    }
}
```

This will make it easier to read and maintain your code as once you've determined that the letter hasn't been used you will only need to call it once. Whereas before you might have had duplication as it looks like it was only been executed for vowels

---

Below are the changes I made to your code when testing in case they are of use:

```
public class AlphabetGuess extends Application {
    private String vowels = "AEIOU";

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        ObservableList<Text> alphabet = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        for(char letter = 'A'; letter <= 'Z'; letter++){
            alphabet.add(new Text(String.valueOf(letter)));
        }

        HBox alphabetContainer = new HBox(5);
        alphabetContainer.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        alphabetContainer.getChildren().addAll(alphabet);

        ToggleButton button = new ToggleButton("Listen for guess");
        button.setSelected(false);

        VBox root = new VBox(20, alphabetContainer, button);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 100);
        scene.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
            //If the button isn't selected, don't process the input
            if (event.getText().isEmpty() || !button.isSelected()) {
                return;
            }

            char userGuess = event.getText().toUpperCase().charAt(0);
            if ((userGuess < 'A' || userGuess > 'Z')) {
                return;
            }

            //This will cause letters A-Z to become 0-25 allowing the list to be indexed
            Text text = alphabet.get(userGuess - 'A');
            if (text.isStrikethrough()) {
                System.out.println(userGuess + " has already been guessed");
                return;
            } else {
                text.setFill(Color.BLUE);
                text.setStrikethrough(true);
                checkPhrase(userGuess);
            }
            //Un-select button which will cause this event to reject incoming keys
            button.setSelected(false);
        });

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void checkPhrase(char chosenLetter){
        //Handle the Hangman-like logic here
        boolean isVowel = vowels.indexOf(chosenLetter) >= 0;
        if (isVowel) {
            System.out.println("User provided a vowel");
        }
        //ToDo: Implement
    }
}
```

Comment: So i'm not sure the toggle button would help much due to the way the rest of the program is set out. so what happens is as follows :
Buttons on GUI pressed -> a switch method run-> In some instances the above method should run once through. This would be the new letter value. The listener needs to stop. I think the issue here is the return statements. I need a way of only accepting one key pressed that is a letter not chosen before.

Comment: The issue is that the scene.setOnKeyPress sits in a method.

Comment: Is your switch statement able to determine when to listen again? If it can, then the button based logic can be removed and mimicked there

Comment: You could set a boolean before entering your switch statement based on some common feature of the wheel results and check that instead a button being selected. E.g. If the wheel has numbers 1-5 and you only need to check input if it's greater than 4

Comment: If polling a variable becomes a performance issue, you could look into replacing/combining it with adding/removing the event handler so you only use it when you need it: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/filters.htm

Comment: Thank you so much. The boolean check fixed everything with a consume method. Much appreciated.